# Is there a way to generate tone from flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have been searching for the ways about it, but seems like there is not much support for generating tone as of right now, or needs to go through the process of generating a tone file, which then is played right after.

Is there a way to generate song then plays next, without the process of generating the file then plays this file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't even think Flutter provides an out-of-the-box way to play sounds. You need to rely on packages :

If you're looking to trigger native "beep" sounds from the OS : [flutter_beep](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_beep)

If you want to generate a soundwave : [sound_generator](https://pub.dev/packages/sound_generator)

Comment: Ah, thanks. Sound generator sounds like what I would want, as it seems providing an ability to generate sounds, + changes frequency. Do you know if there is one that provides for both ios and android?

Comment: I don't think there is. You can upvote [this issue](https://github.com/mertguner/sound_generator/issues/1) to show you need it. You can also try and develop the iOS platform side yourself.

Comment: the flutter_beep plugin is no longer maintaned, but it was great.